# Calculate Max and min dates

Tags: date, powerbi

i'm trying to calculate the max ( and min )  of a date.

My situation is the following.

I've create a date table like this:

```
Date = 
ADDCOLUMNS (
CALENDAR (DATE(2008;1;1); DATE(2020;12;31));
"DateAsInteger"; FORMAT ( [Date]; "YYYYMMDD" );
"Year"; YEAR ( [Date] );
"Monthnumber"; FORMAT ( [Date]; "MM" );"Daynumber"; FORMAT ( [Date]; "DD" );
"YearMonthnumber"; FORMAT ( [Date]; "YYYY/MM" );
"YearMonthShort"; FORMAT ( [Date]; "YYYY/mmm" );
"MonthNameShort"; FORMAT ( [Date]; "mmm" );
"MonthNameLong"; FORMAT ( [Date]; "mmmm" );
"DayOfWeekNumber"; WEEKDAY ( [Date] );
"DayOfWeek"; FORMAT ( [Date]; "dddd" );
"DayOfWeekShort"; FORMAT ( [Date]; "ddd" );
"Quarter"; "Q" & FORMAT ( [Date]; "Q" );
"YearQuarter"; FORMAT ( [Date]; "YYYY" ) & "/Q" & FORMAT ( [Date]; "Q" );
"WeekNum"; WEEKNUM ( [Date] )
)
```

I have a table  "Table 1" like  this :

```
ID  ForeignKey  Date
1   A           01/01/2005
2   A           05/04/2008
3   A           31/12/2019
4   B           15/3/2017
5   B           16/05/2018
6   B           15/04/2019
7   C           05/06/2006
8   C           04/12/2015
9   C           15/04/2019
```

And another table "Table 2" like this

```
ID2 Price
A   100
B   500
C   650
```

The "Date" table  is related to "Table1" by date and Table 1 is related to  "Table 2" by Table1.ForeignKey = Table2.ID2.

In my report i have a date slicer which is set for example to filter dates between Jan 1 2008 and June 30 2018.
My goal is  to calculate the max and min date for each one of table 2 in the selected period like this:

```
ID2 Price   MinDate         MaxDate
A   100     05/04/2008      05/04/2008
B   500     15/3/2017       16/05/2018
C   650     04/12/2015      04/12/2015
```

All i am able to achieve by doing somethig like this

```
MaxDate= CALCULATE ( LASTDATE ( Table1[Date] ); FILTER (
ALLSELECTED('Date') ;
'Date'[Date] <= Max('Date'[Date])
))
```

is the max and min dates in  the whole calendar (01/01/2008 - 12/31/2020) , which is not what i'm trying to do .

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

With the relationships you describe, simply use measures:

```
MinDate = CALCULATE ( MIN ( 'Table 1'[Date] ) )
```

and

```
MaxDate = CALCULATE ( MAX ( 'Table 1'[Date] ) )
```

And set your slicer on `'Date'[Date]`

See https://pwrbi.com/so_55373837/ for example PBIX file